# How can I save the values entered at design time for a complex property?

Tags: .net, properties, typeconverter, uitypeeditor

I'm still learning the ropes when it comes to implementing custom editors for complex properties at design time.

As a simple *starting* point, I'm trying to enable design-time editing of a property of type `ICollection<string>`.

What I've done so far is:

- Wrote a `StringsEditor` class, which derives from `UITypeEditor` and displays a drop-down into which the developer can input a bunch of strings on separate lines, which are subsequently added to a collection. This works fine.
- Wrote a `StringsConverter` class, which derives from `TypeConverter` and converts between objects of type `string` and `ICollection<string>` (well, any type `T` that implements `ICollection<string>`) so that when the developer closes the drop-down displayed by the `StringsEditor`, the text that appears in the box is a comma-delimited list of the strings entered. Reopening the drop-down displays the strings again, one per line.

The result of my work so far is that everything appears to work great during design time. The user can modify the property, adding and removing strings to his/her heart's content and the text displayed in the property grid matches what's in the collection.

What I haven't been able to figure out yet--and this doesn't surprise me-- is how to actually save this collection beyond design time, so that the values entered... you know, *stay there*. My understanding is that currently, the property is being edited at design time (by me), but since none of the changes I'm applying have any effect on the generated `InitializeComponent` method of the control, there's no effect on the *class* I'm designing (only the *instance* presently displayed by my IDE).

But obviously, it is possible to get your values into that `InitializeComponent` call. In fact, I just happened by accident to discover that this magically "just works" for properties of type `DirectoryInfo` with an appropriate `UITypeEditor` (I made another editor called `DirectoryEditor` that just displays a `FolderBrowserDialog` and provides a `DirectoryInfo` object for whatever path is selected, and this surprisingly *did* end up updating the class's `InitializeComponent` method). So I know it can be done. I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you mark the property which exposes the collection as a content property with the [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] attribute? I think collections need to be marked with this to be serialized.